# Why is Kabuto referred to as "Four Eyes"?

Tags: naruto

During the fight between Jiraiya and Tsunade against Orochimaru and Kabuto in the *Search for Tsunade Arc*, Jiraiya refers to Kabuto as "Four Eyes". Why did he get that name?

Comment: It is a slang for persons wearing pair of glasses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because he was the only one among all present there that was wearing a pair of glasses.
The term ["Four eyes"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/four-eyes) refers to people that wear spectacles.

Answer (score 7):

I don't recall the scene. But in Japanese, he probably actually referred to him as [*megane*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Megane) (meaning *spectacles*). Rather than using literal translations, subbers/dubbers prefer to use equivalent terms which will carry a similar tone in the target language. Since an equivalent epithet used in English for a bespectacled person is [four-eyes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/four-eyes), that is what was preferred.

*Four-eyes* is almost always used as a derogatory term in English. But this isn't necessarily the case with *megane*. That said, considering the character of *Kabuto*, I expect that that is how it was used in this case. IOW, *four-eyes* is a perfect fit.